# Cache busting and Subversion

Tags: svn, caching, web-applications

In our web application, whenever I change something in a JavaScript or CSS file, there is the following workflow:

1. Make the change.
2. Test it.
3. Commit the change in Subversion. The file has not date postfix because I would lose change history.
4. In the html file, where the changed JavaScript or CSS resource is referenced, I change the file in question, for instance from "core_2015_07_01.js" to "core_2015_07_14.js".
5. The tiresome excercise is now to change the date in every html file where it   is referenced.
6. When I create a new html file that needs this JavaScript file, I need some place that informs me, which date I have to add in order to get it right (because I do not see it in the source in Subversion).

I'm content about the cache busting technique by itself, but I'm not content with the handling of the files in Subversion and on the way to the deployment.

Has somebody found a better way of managing the files in and around Subversion?

Answer (score 1):

In my past projects, I have solved this problem in two ways:

1. I was using Grunt for my project. This has a plugin for asset versioning. 
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-assets-versioning
2. I was using Apache where I defined a rewrite rule for javascript/css files. 
   http://www.particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/

There should be other solutions as well depending on the environment you are working. The idea is to keep your js and css name without any version. But generate files with a version and provide a way for server to understand the filenames. Hope this helps.